# Android HttpRequest

Tags: android, http, asynchronous, android-asynctask

In Android i'm sending multiple request to the server for each request server will send a response.Now my problem is identify for which request response is received.
please suggest someway of sending your HTTP request using a Tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Synchronized for Receiving a Response.